# how do I add “contact page or custom link” at top menu bar in OpenCart 3.0.2.0

Tags: opencart

I cant find a way to add contact us and about us links in top menu bar in open cart 3.0.2.0
 i have searched open cart forums and i have tried stack overflow links  but nothing works kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple/novice way is to hard-code them directly in your:

catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.twig file

One thing to note, the contact page actually is already linked there. However, the link is embedded in the "phone" icon at the top of the page (assuming you are using the default installation and did not customize anything yet). If you click it, you'll notice it takes you the contact page. You can see my attached screenshot, too.[image]

For further reference anyhow, once you open the header.twig file, look at around line 46, and you'll see the corresponding link/code for that contact page:

```
<li><a href="{{ contact }}"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ telephone }}</span></li>
```

So the link is embedded into that font awesome icon for the phone. You can remove the font awesome (i class) tag and write out "Contact Us" or whatever you want.

An easy way for you to also add custom links, you can go log into your admin section. Go to "Catalog" and then click on "information." You'll notice the default informational pages are listed there that correspond to the links you see in your footer/bottom section of your front-end site. You can add more pages there and then link them through your catalog header.twig file.

There are better/advanced ways to implement custom links. But based on your question, the above steps are probably easier for you to manage. However, if you are including external links to other sites, then just hard-code them in hrefs directly on your page.